# How to save a value in android to use later

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to store a string  value and need to retrieve even  the app is reopened  and pass it to another activity to use in that activity. Can somebody guide me here with a sample code/project please

Comment: Use shared preference. see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Please search before asking really basic questions.

Comment: If you could show what you have already tried, it will be easier for someone to help you improve or fix your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use Shared  Preferences, presented in the developers android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) . More indications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826735/how-to-store-persistent-data-easily-without-using-databases)

As explained in the Android documentation:

```
final String KEY = "stringKey";
String myString = "someStringContent";
// We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
// All objects are from android.context.Context
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // this = your Context
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(KEY, myString);

// Apply the edits! This happens asynchronously
editor.apply();
```

And later, to retrieve that value when your app is reopened:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String myString = settings.getString(KEY, "default value");
```